# Does it make a difference if you iterate over a list or a tuple in Python?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying the [wemake-python-styleguide](https://pypi.org/project/wemake-python-styleguide/) and found [WPS335](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/violations/consistency.html#wemake_python_styleguide.violations.consistency.WrongLoopIterTypeViolation):

> Using lists, dicts, and sets do not make much sense. You can use tuples instead. Using comprehensions implicitly create a two level loops, that are hard to read and deal with.

It gives this example:

```py
# Correct:
for person in ('Kim', 'Nick'):
    ...

# Wrong:
for person in ['Kim', 'Nick']:
    ...
```

Is this purely personal preference or is there more that speaks for using a tuple? I can only think about speed, but I cannot imagine that this makes a difference.

I think I have seen more people using lists and I wonder if there is a reason to change it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see what they have against sets. If I want to process `a`, `b` and `c` and they could be duplicates of each other, I think `for x in {a, b, c}:` is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: And of course, since `set`s are unordered, but `dict`s in 3.7+ are ordered, a reasonable case for using `dict` to get `a, b, c` in order, but with duplicates removed, would be doing `for x in dict.fromkeys((a, b, c)):`. But I have to admit both use cases are pretty unusual.

Comment: I think this only applies to situations where `set` `list` and `tuple` are interchangeable without changing any code. In this case, use a tuple.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not sure they're against that. The way the page puts it, they forbid looping over *any* set/dict/etc. So you can't do `for x in s:` if `s` is a set. Surely they don't mean that. I suspect they mean displays, which your example isn't.

Comment: This assertion that *"Using lists, dicts, and sets do not make much sense"* seems like a preference. I mean why even use parentheses `for person in 'Kim', 'Nick'`? Seems arbitrary.

Comment: Not sure if they're fully consistent with themselves, here they're looping over a [list](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/violations/consistency.html#wemake_python_styleguide.violations.consistency.UselessContinueViolation). On a side note, I'm curious what their thoughts are on `for key, value in dict.items()` or when a list is passed in by assigned name `for item in some_list: do_something(item)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using lists instead of tuples *as constants* makes no difference in CPython. As of some versions, both are compiled to tuples.

```py
>>> dis.dis("""
... for person in ["Kim", "Nick"]:
...     ...
... """)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              12 (to 14)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (('Kim', 'Nick'))
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 12)
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (person)

  3          10 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   12 POP_BLOCK
        >>   14 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note how the list literal was transformed to a `LOAD_CONST (('Kim', 'Nick'))` instruction of a tuple.

---

As for preference, CPython prefers `tuple`. If you have the choice, you should do so as well.

Comment: Note that this is an implementation detail of CPython; there is no rule requiring this translation (older versions of CPython didn't do it), and the translation will not be performed if any members of the `list` aren't immutable literals. Using a `tuple` in those cases will be (trivially) faster and more memory-efficient.